# Using dataframe column names inside select statement inside function for use with map()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Today I began working with purrr functions so I can try and use R from a more functional approach. I currently have a dataframe that contains a response variable with a lot of other variables. My goal is to split the dataframe by the levels in the response column, and then run shapiro.test() on all of the split dataframes.

For example, this code works:

```
# fake data 
df = data.frame(y = c(rep(1,10), rep(2, 10)), 
                a = rnorm(20),
                b = runif(20), 
                c = rnorm(20))

df$y <- factor(df$y)    

df %>% 
    select(y, a) %>% 
    split(.$y) %>% 
    map(~shapiro.test(.x$a))
```

And this returns:

```
$`1`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  .x$a
W = 0.93455, p-value = 0.4941


$`2`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  .x$a
W = 0.7861, p-value = 0.009822
```

So this works as I want it to on an individual column, but I would like it to run on a given vector of any columns. My thinking right now is to create a vector of the column names I want to run and use that in a map(). I think I'm pretty close to having this right, but I'm just a little stuck.

```
# Function that splits the df into two groups based on y levels and run shapiro test on the split dfs
shapiro <- function(var) {
  df_list = df %>% 
    select(y, var) %>% 
    split(.$y) %>% 
    map(~shapiro.test(.x$var))
  return(df_list)
}
```

This fails:

```
> shapiro(a)
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found
```

Which makes sense since a is not saved in the environment. This is sort of the direction I envision it to, but I don't know if there's a better way to go about it.

```
# the column names I want the function to take
columns = c(a, b, c)

# map it
map(columns, shapiro)
```

However, this gives an error since the column names aren't in the environment. Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this or improve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with a function, you'll likely need to get into [tidyeval](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), like @MauritsEvers answer. For a relatively small task like this, you could instead get away with a couple `map` calls. Map over the list of data frames created by splitting by `y`, then use `map_at` to apply the test to the columns of your choice.

In the first method, you end up with some excess—any columns *not* in the `map_at` are just hanging there. The cleaner way is to select the columns you want, and then `map` over all columns to apply the test.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_list1 <- df %>%
  split(.$y) %>%
  map(function(split_by_y) {
    split_by_y %>%
      map_at(vars(a, b, c), shapiro.test)
  })

test_list2 <- df %>%
  split(.$y) %>%
  map(function(split_by_y) {
    split_by_y %>%
      select(a, b, c) %>%
      map(shapiro.test)
  })

test_list2[[2]]$a
#> 
#>  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 
#> data:  .x[[i]]
#> W = 0.95281, p-value = 0.7018
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` way with three corrections/improvements:

1. In your example call `shapiro(a)`, you provide the column as a symbol, so we need to make sure that `a` is properly quoted and then later un-quoted to adhere to `dplyr`s non-standard evaluation.
2. Instead of `split` a more `tidyverse`-consistent approach is to use `nest`.
3. Lastly, I would recommend making `df` a function argument of `shapiro`, thereby avoiding the dependence on a global variable.

This is the improved version

```
shapiro <- function(df, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  df_list <- df %>%
      select(y, !!var) %>%
      group_by(y) %>%
      nest() %>%
      mutate(test = map(setNames(data, y), ~shapiro.test(.x[[1]]))) %>%
      pull(test)
  return(df_list)
}
```

So for column `df$a`

```
shapiro(df, a)
#$`1`
#
#   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#
#data:  .x[[1]]
#W = 0.93049, p-value = 0.4527
#
#
#$`2`
#
#   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#
#data:  .x[[1]]
#W = 0.9268, p-value = 0.4171
```

and for column `df$b`

```
shapiro(df, b)
#$`1`
#
#   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#
#data:  .x[[1]]
#W = 0.90313, p-value = 0.237
#
#
#$`2`
#
#   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#
#data:  .x[[1]]
#W = 0.88552, p-value = 0.1509
```

Comment: Thank you! This introduces a lot of new things that I'll have to explore further!

Answer (score 0):

You can append the results to a list using a for loop:

```
shapiro <- function(var) {
   myList = list()
   for (i in 1:length(var)) {
     myList[[i]] = df %>% 
     select(y, var = var[i]) %>% 
     split(.$y) %>% 
     map(~shapiro.test(.x$var))
   }
   return(myList)
}
```

Just make sure to use a character vector for the columns:

```
shapiro(c("a", "b"))
```